# How to load javascript on specific page only

Tags: xml, layout, magento

Possible duplicate : [How to include Javascript in xml-document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384639/how-to-include-javascript-in-xml-document)

How would I load a javascript file only only checkout pages?  We are using onepage checkout.  I have tried adding

```
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>myscript.js</script>
            </action>
```

To various places on checkout.xml with no success

Comment: This does not seem like a duplicate at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page frame for the onepage checkout is loaded in the initial action. Try something like this:

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
    <reference name="head">  
         <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/myscript.js</name></action>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

Then place your script in your skin directory under `/js`.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe