# How can I use Google XML suggestions with jquery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I have found a way to get Google suggestions with XML, Its an address like this:

[This is suggestions for the word Cars](http://google.com/complete/search?q=cars&output=toolbar)

My question is how can I get XML to show as a proper HTML ul/li when regeusting with an input field. So typing in input field would get XML list and show it as regular HTML list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use XSLT

- [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Mozilla_JavaScript_interface_to_XSL_Transformations)

But you will run into the problem that you cannot just simply import XML to HTML in Internet Explorer.

---

So, for your purpose just iterate on the relevant `Node`s

```
var xml = new DOMParser( ).parseFromString(/*xml string*/,"text/xml") ;

var l1 = xml.getElementsByTagName("suggestion") ;
var l2 = xml.getElementsByTagName("num_queries") ;

var d = document.createElement("div") ;

    if(l1.length === l2.length) {

         for(var i = 0, u, s, q , e; i < l1.length ; i++) {

             u = document.createElement("ul") ;
             d.appendChild(u) ;

             s = l1[i] ;
             q = l2[i] ;

             e = document.createElement("li") ;
             e.appendChild(  document.createTextNode( s.getAttribute("data") )  ) ;
             u.appendChild(e) ;

             e = document.createElement("li") ;
             e.appendChild(  document.createTextNode( q.getAttribute("int") )  ) ;
             u.appendChild(e) ;

        }

    }

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(d) ;
```

---

1. [Preview on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/azisuk/edit#preview)

Comment: That will only get me the xml for the word 'cars' Im trying to mimic the google suggestions list, so I have to get a different list with every time I press a key in an input field. I already ask this question over here: http://webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=248975 But for some reason suddenly it stopt working and I dont know what the problem is..Becouse the xml google is providing is still functional.

Comment: @Youss: the output depends on the input XML document. You just need to replace the `xml` variable with the result of any query. The format of the output XML delivered by Google remains the same, hence the code will still work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to include JavaScript into XML here is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1451526/1065429

If you just want to display text with a bullet point use CSS: display: list-item

Comment: The question, I believe, is how to put XML into HTML not how to put JavaScript code into HTML.

Comment: In that case it would have to be XHTML 1.1 and nothing less strict and then since you are already in a natively XML document just add bits from other XML languages using namespaces.

Comment: I recommend reading the OP's question again. Hint: he wants HTML output.