# JavaScript in xml file

Tags: javascript, xml

I am making ssrs report which has xml file.

I want to call a javascript [for tooltip] from xml itself.

I know that I can put it in the page where it to be deployed, but in my perticular scenario it's not possible.

FYI:

- The javascript is for tooltip and its using jQuery and css files.
- Its working fine in html,aspx page.

File to include for the script:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://.../SiteAssets/Styles/master.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://.../SiteAssets/Styles/jquery.qtip.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://.../SiteAssets/Styles/demos.css" />
```

And the script is :

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // We'll target all DIV elements with title tags.)
        $('div[title]').qtip(
{
    content: {
        attr: 'title' // Use the jstooltip attribute of the area map for the content
    },
    style: {
        classes: 'ui-tooltip-tipsy ui-tooltip-shadow'
    }
});
    });


</script>
```

Any idea / other way?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Comment: What div elements do you have in your XML?
Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384639/how-to-include-javascript-in-xml-document

Comment: Its <Tooltip>Some tooltip</Tooltip> not div. sorry.


And I also tried the above link instruction but it didnt work.