# Why is XML not intended to be used as a presentation language?

Tags: javascript, xml, oop, xhtml, presentation

I am interested in creating web applications that are as simple as possible, and not simpler. I mean, it seems to me that I could (*should be able to*) create an XML document that represents the objects of my application, use CSS as the "presentation layer", and Javascript to manipulate the objects.

Part of what I am saying is that it seems to me that HTML obfuscates the application by mixing objects with presentation formatting, isn't this the point of CSS? -- HTML/XML: what data, CSS: how to present the data, (JS: how to manipulate the data)

I *could* use XLST to transform the XML into XHTML, but then the JS has to be coded for the XHTML (presentation elements) and not the XML (data objects), which adds unnecessary complexity.

I'm coming from the perspective of a programmer, with the desire to use design principles such as separating the presentation from the data (HTML/XML vs CSS) and object-oriented programming. Would it not not make sense to say that presently HTML and CSS are necessary to "define" the presentation layer?

Comments I'm looking for are about the proper way to code, not "fixes" with current standards.

Here is an example. I could write this:

HTML/XHTML:

```
<ul class="folderTree">
    <li class="fTreeItem"><img /><span class="fTreeItemName">Directory</span>
        <ul class="fTreeItemContents">
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

...but the design principles could be better satisfied if I could do this:

```
<folderTree>
    <item><img /><name>Directory</name>
        <folderTree>
            ...
        </folderTree>
    </item>
</folderTree>
```

and include the following CSS:

```
folderTree { display: block; }
folderTree item { display: list-item; }
folderTree name { display: inline; }
```

This seems to me to be the proper way to present the data. Do you not agree? Please explain...

Edit: The foundation of my question rests on the facts that a) user-defined tags can't be used in HTML/XHTML, and b) javascript isn't meant to be used with XML.

Edit 2: Also, I'm not completely familiar with how multiple namespaces are handled in a document. So if someone could shed light on if I could achieve my goal by using an XHTML document and including my XML code/tags using another namespace...

Comment: XHTML is XML, thus XML can be used as a presentation language.

Comment: You should look into the Google [Polymer project.](http://www.polymer-project.org/)

Comment: fact `a` in your edit isn't exactly true. For example, if you were using angularjs, the markup you are using would be perfectly fine, you would have a directive that handles folderTree with sub directives for the child tags. It may not validate in an html validator, but it will work in all modern browsers (and IE8+) *(terminology might be a bit off, relatively new to angularjs)*

Comment: @MrMojoRisin Again, please don't use `code ticks` for highlighting software names.

Comment: I don't quite understand how you came to the conclusion of javascript not being meant for interacting with xml. XML is just a way of presenting data, just like json. Why would javascript not be meant to interact with it? XML just has the advantage of being styleable via css where as json would first have to be converted to html or xml.

Comment: @KevinB I'm not talking about the ability to manipulate an XML object with Javascript. I'm talking about manipulating XML when it is the document object. See answer by Ady and the comments with it in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/384667/3724094)

Comment: Then i guess i don't quite get your question. Why can't we use XML as a presentation layer? because that's not what it's for. Use XHTML instead. However, if your end goal is to be able to use user-defined tags, you can already do that with HTML5 in modern browsers and most common old browsers. http://jsfiddle.net/Ur32A/

Comment: @KevinB I'm specifically stating I DON'T want to use XML as a presentation layer... I'm saying I want to use it as a data layer (what it was meant for), use CSS as the presentation layer (what it was meant for), and use JS as the means to manipulate the data. It seems XML wasn't meant to be manipulated as a document itself, but merely as data interchange. I am interested in using XML not as data interchange but as a data object and JS to manipulate.

As far as HTML5, ok thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: The way you're describing it though makes XML the presentation layer, which it cannot be. XML should be used to generate the presentation layer (html, html5, or xhtml). CSS then styles the presentation layer, and js interacts with it. How you convert the xml to html can be done in several ways of course.

Comment: Check [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/185667)

Answer (score 2):

HTML has elements and attributes with defined meanings. They are understood by a wide variety of clients, including common visual web browsers, search engine indexing robots and screen readers. It has some legacy presentation attributes and elements left over, but they have mostly been removed or marked as to be avoided.

Your custom XML language might have elements and attributes with more specific meanings than those in HTML, but they won't be meanings understood by clients. You could handle that for visual users with a stylesheet, but wouldn't serve search engine, screen reader and other users all that well.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to run your application inside a browser. Browser's language for rendering UI is HTML/XHTML. If you want to have your own language for defining UI you will need to translate it to something browser understands. This can be done JIT or on page load.

I agree with you that running XSLT makes javascript part more complicated. But what you can do is to write an "interpreter" (or a "rendering engine") in javascript. So that your application will be written in XML+CSS+JavaScript, but instead of running it on naked browser - you will use a library that will render your XML-UI using "HTML instructions".

It can be as simple as XML nodes substitution, so that when you say  in your XML - it will produce  in HTML. Depending on how you connect your javascript to your presentation definition, you will need to provide an adapter of some sort for javascript access. For example you could "intercept" jQuery $(...) calls and substitute $("folderTree") for $("div.folderTree"). But if you access your UI elements using proper page-objects already, then the logic of translation can be encapsulated in this page-object. I.e. PageObject class can be smart enough to know that when you ask for treeFolder node, it needs to look for $("div.treeFolder") rather than $("treeFolder").

Take a look at [angular.js's directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the upcoming [web components](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/) and [current libraries](http://webcomponents.org/) you can use nearly any element you want. You can then apply a stylesheet to it and it will display fine.

```
<tralala>Hello World!</tralala>

<style>
tralala {
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

Have a look at the current web component libraries and probably use XSL to modify your data to match web components.

Answer (score 0):

From the W3C the [design goals](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-origin-goals) for XML are :

1. XML shall be straightforwardly usable over the Internet.
2. XML shall support a wide variety of applications.
3. XML shall be compatible with SGML.
4. It shall be easy to write programs which process XML documents.
5. The number of optional features in XML is to be kept to the absolute minimum, ideally zero.
6. XML documents should be human-legible and reasonably clear.
7. The XML design should be prepared quickly.
8. The design of XML shall be formal and concise.
9. XML documents shall be easy to create.
10. Terseness in XML markup is of minimal importance.

XML is firstly about Well-Formed XML documents, and then Valid XML Documents to a specific XML Application definition, i.e. the XML Document is valid to XHTML version 1.0.

There are thousand of XML Application definitions out there, representing impossible to visualise data, at impossible in a generic way.