# JQuery AND OR operators on if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, thymeleaf

I am using **thymeleaf** and Spring Boot to parse an entity.

I'm trying to change a `boolean` field value to `String` like 'yes' or 'No' but as simple as it seems, I am getting the following error:

> 12:54:30.046 [XNIO-2 task-17] ERROR o.t.templateparser.ErrorHandler -
>   [THYMELEAF][XNIO-2 task-17] Fatal error during parsing
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must go inmediately
>   after the '&' in the entity reference.
>
> Exception parsing document: template="scenariosList", line 401 -
>   column 21

This is my last try in javascript:

```
var modificat = $("#modificatEscenari").val();
var calculat = $("#calculatEscenari").val();

if (calculat) {
    $("#calculat").val("Sí");
} else {
    $("#calculat").val("No");
    $("#calculPendent").val("Sí");
}

if (modificat) {
    $("#calculPendent").val("Sí");
}

if (!modificat && calculat) {
    $('#calculPendent').val("No");
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in this code `if (!modificat && calculat) {...` I have read the use of operators in `if` statements and it looks good to me.

**EDIT**

It's wrapped like

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
        ....
        doing my stuff and the piece of code that trigger the exception
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: It's find Javascript, I guess Thymeleaf uses `&&` for its own purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception makes it clear that you're embedding JavaScript code in an XML document. So naturally, `&&` fails, because `&` indicates the beginning of a numbered or named character entity (like `&nbsp;` or `&#1234;`).

Possible solutions:

1. Don't embed JavaScript code in XML. Use a separate JavaScript file that you refer to from the XML. (This would be what I'd do if I were you.)
2. Mark it up in a `CDATA` section. [This question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384639/how-to-include-javascript-in-xml-document) talk about how to do that, for instance [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16426395/157247) says it should be:

   ```
   <script xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><![CDATA[
   // Your code here
   ]]></script>
   ```
3. Laborious ensure that the text of the JavaScript code is valid XML text, which would be A) Painful, and B) A maintenance nightmare. But for instance, the `&&` operator would have to be written as `&amp;&amp;`.

Answer (score -1):

Related: [The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303779/the-entity-name-must-immediately-follow-the-in-the-entity-reference)

To summarize: The & character is a special character used by the XML Parser inside Thymeleaf.
Use `&amp;` for the & character instead.

Your line would look like this:

```
if(!modificat &amp;&amp; calculat){
```

Comment: This actually leeds to a syntax error caused by the ';' after &amp

Comment: @JM.Palomo: It shouldn't, the `;` is part of the named character entity. The XML text `if(!modificat &amp;&amp; calculat){`, when read by the parser, is `if(!modificat && calculat){` which works just fine when it's given to the JavaScript engine.