# Date Format from (20180810) to (10 Aug 2018)

Tags: javascript, xml, odata, sapui5

Anyone can help me out with the date format?

I have tried `new Date(NumberValue)` but returning Invalid Date

MockServer:

```
"NumberValue": "2.018081E7"
```

Formatter:

```
 if(ValueType === "D"){
                    return parseFloat(NumberValue);
```

Comment: @userfrh The `"NumberValue"` property doesn't seem to be of type `Edm.DateTime` (OData V2) or `Edm.Date` (OData V4). Please make sure first to have a proper EDM type for all properties that hold date values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex to split your date string into year, month, day, which you can then pass to `new Date()`

```js
const s = '20180810'

const rx = /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/
let [_, Y, M, D] = s.match(rx)

console.log(new Date(Y, M - 1 , D)) // month is zero indexed
```

**Edit based on comment:**
If you can use destructuring — `match()` just returns an array so you can use indexes for the same effect:

```js
var s = '20180810'

var rx = /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/
var m = s.match(rx)

console.log(new Date(m[1], m[2] - 1, m[3])) // month is zero indexed
```

Comment: Hey, thanks it does work when im using ES6. But unfortunately im using Javascript ES5.let [_, Y, M, D] = s.match(rx) this code somehow does not work for me. I've inspect and it stated s.match is not a function.

Comment: @userfrh `match()` just returns an array, so you can save it as an array and index into it. See edit.

Comment: s.match still appear not a function. I tried to do var rx = new RegExp('/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/'); like this as well.

Comment: That’s strange @userfrh `match()` has been around for a longtime - ECMAScript 3 I think. Are you sure your starting with a string. Is it possible `20180810` is a number or `s` is not defined?

Answer (score -1):

You could achieve use [**`moment.js`**](https://momentjs.com/)

```js
var val = parseFloat(2.018081E7);
var date = moment(val,'YYYYMMDD').format('DD MMM YYYY');
console.log(date)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm still new at this, where should i put <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>? Since im using XML.

Comment: @userfrh for you reference [`script include xml`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384639/how-to-include-javascript-in-xml-document)