json-doc returns blank page in a stylesheet when opened in browser
When I use the json-doc in a browser within XSLT for read XML and produces HTML browsers (Firefox, Chrome and Safari) return blank page.
the part of XSLT is like this:
<td>
  <xsl:variable name="activityLink" select="json-doc(concat('https://deims.org/api/activities/', substring-after(//cs:campaign, 'https://deims.org/activity/')))"/>
    <a href="{//cs:campaign}" target="_blank">
      <xsl:value-of select="$activityLink?title"/>
    </a>
</td>

the section about the cs:campaign is:
<cs:campaign>https://deims.org/activity/50d7a52d-e384-4ed4-9976-5bf9c8302843</cs:campaign>
I aspecting the title of this:
<td>Lago di Garda - Italy ...</td>

json-doc is not part of xslt-1.0. See i.e.: https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/functions/fn/json-doc.html

I am using version 2.0 <xsl:stylesheet ... indent="yes"/>

Change the xslt tag then

Does this question give some clarity: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65885895/3710053

With SaxonJS 2 this works:


const xml = `<sample>https://deims.org/api/activities/50d7a52d-e384-4ed4-9976-5bf9c8302843</sample>`;

const xslt = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:template match="sample">
    <xsl:copy>{json-doc(.)?title}</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:next-match/>
    <xsl:comment>Run with {system-property('xsl:product-name')} {system-property('xsl:product-version')} {system-property('Q{http://saxon.sf.net/}platform')}</xsl:comment>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
`;

const result = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`
  transform(map {
    'stylesheet-text' : $xslt,
    'source-node' : parse-xml($xml),
    'delivery-format' : 'serialized'
  })?output`,
  null,
  { params : { xml : xml, xslt : xslt } }
);

console.log(result);
<script src="https://martin-honnen.github.io/SaxonJS-2.6/SaxonJS2.js"></script>




I'm not familiar with SaxonJS2.
Do you think it is possible to include your code within xslt?
<script src="https://martin-honnen.github.io/SaxonJS-2.6/SaxonJS2.js"></script>
<xsl:variable name="activityLink"
                                select="concat('https://deims.org/api/activities/', substring-after(//cs:campaign, 'https://deims.org/activity/'))"/>
<script>
  const xml = `<activity><xsl:value-of select="$activityLink"/></activity>`;                           
  ...console.log(result);
</script>
<a href="{//cs:campaign}" target="_blank">
  <div id="console"/>
</a>


Well, I posted a link to SaxonJS home page, it is https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml, its documentation (linked from there) is at https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html. You will need to read it if you want to use XSLT 3 in the browser, as browsers only support XSLT 1 natively. The json-doc function is part of XPath 3.1 so you will only find support for it if you use an XSLT 3 processor like SaxonJS. It is not clear what you are asking about "it is possible to include your code within xslt", I have posted JavaScript code that uses SaxonJS to execute XSLT 3 code.

Thanks Martin, I read the documentation further. I could not reproduce your code in an HTML page. Solved!
